# slime-ac does not work with sbcl 1.2.13 and slime 2.14 on OSX 10.9.5

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, common-lisp, slime

It's very confusing when I use slime-ac with sbcl 1.1.17 and slime 2013-04-02 everything works great but once I upgrade sbcl and slime, slime-ac stops working. Does slime-ac need to rebuild a dict or something?

I guess I'll just keep using the older compiler and slime since it works but I would really like to find an answer to this.

Comment: I don't have a solid answer to your question but if you aren't already, I would recommend using quicklisp to manage your slime install. I have yet to hit an issue that wasn't resolved by running the quicklisp update. Sorry I couldn't more directly address your question though.

Comment: Thats Ok! I'm about to do that now.